# Storing a 4x4 2D-matrix in RAM using encoding algorithm to achieve minimum RAM-space usage

Tags: java, performance, session, ram

[image]

A board with 16 cells (4x4 matrix) exists of numbers from 1 to 15 (there is such a game). One cell is empty.

How to store the matrix data in RAM using minimum possible space of it?

I have made an example of a class `Board` which can be stored in RAM as an object consisting of just one `long` property representing the encoded version of the matrix.

Here is my `Board` class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Board implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long board; // the only property which is stored in RAM

    public Board() {
        board = 0x123456789abcdef0L; // 0 represents the empty-cell
    }

    public int[][] getBoardMatrix() { // decoding algorithm
        int[][] boardMatrix = new int[BoardController.ROWS][BoardController.COLUMNS];
        String boardString = getBoardString();
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < BoardController.ROWS; rowIndex++) {
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < BoardController.COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                boardMatrix[rowIndex][colIndex] = Integer.valueOf(
                        String.valueOf(boardString.charAt(rowIndex * BoardController.COLUMNS + colIndex)), 16);
            }
        }
        return boardMatrix;
    }

    public void setBoardByMatrix(int[][] boardMatrix) { // encoding algorithm
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int[] row : boardMatrix) {
            for (int cell : row) {
                sb.append(cell);
            }
        }
        board = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString(), 16);
    }

    private String getBoardString() {
        return String.format("%x", board);
    }
}
```

I make also use of a class, representing a kind-of module or controller with some static properties:

```
public class BoardController {
    public static final int ROWS = 4;
    public static final int COLUMNS = 4;
}
```

My concrete question:
Is there a better way of storing this matrix to achieve a minimum-RAM-usage?

Comment: Use a different programming language so there won't be any of the stuff that Java keeps in by default?

Comment: Is it a matrix of arbitrary int's, or a sequence of numbers from 1 to 15 with an empty cell, where each number can only be once? In the latter case, it can fit into a `long` (because 17! < 2^64).

Comment: @Kayaman My question was: "How to make planes fly faster?". Your answer is: "Don't fly with Lufthansa". I'm not sure it answers my question.

Comment: @LowLevel Your analogy is not apt, but I'll let it *fly*. If you want to minimize RAM usage, don't create a separate `Board` class. The class itself will take several bytes in the memory.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev it's a matrix of numbers from 1 to 15 and an empty cell, and their indexes (places) change multiple times.

Comment: Misread the question, sorry. Thought for a second it was about arbitrary matrices. Anyways, comment != answer.

Comment: @Kayaman It's impossible not to make a separate class, because my question is not: "How to make passangers fly faster", but "How to make planes fly faster"

Comment: @LowLevel Your question was: "How to store the matrix data in RAM using minimum possible space of it?" Next time pay attention when writing your question, even if you might not be a native speaker.

Comment: @Kayaman So, when you see the tag: "Java" it means beans. And my question is actually about the algorithm, not about the direct input of primitive data in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Biggest memory waste: references.**

Don't store an array of Boards - each entry in the array is not a board, but a pointer to a board. This means that you are immediately wasting almost half of the space you could be using. When you save the board, don't save it as a class, but as a long. When you need to work with a board, convert it back from a long to a Board. This way, you can make an array of longs, but still treat them like objects when you want to.

```
class Board
{
    public static Board fromLong(long value) {
        int[] positions = new int[16];
        List<Integer> possibilities = new ArrayList<Integer>(16);
        for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
            possibilities.add(i);

        long ignore = 0;
        for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
            // Rounds towards zero
            long index = (value - ignore) / factorial(i);
            ignore += index * factorial(i);
            positions[i] = possibilities.remove(index);
        }
        positions[0] = possibilities.get(0);

        return new Board(positions);
    }

    /* Note that while this returns a long, only the lowest 45 bits contain data */
    public long toLong() {
        List<Integer> possibilities = new ArrayList<Integer>(16);
        for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
            possibilities.add(i);

        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
            int position = positions[i];
            int index = possibilities.indexOf(position);
            value += index * factorial(i);
            possibilities.remove(index);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not run this code yet, I'm still at work (Just on SO while I wait for compilation).

You can work out how many different combinations this board can produce. Let's treat the empty space as the number 0.

There are 16 unique values for the first tile. Once you know the value of the first tile, there are only 15 possible values for the next tile, and 14 for the third tile. Follow it all the way down to the last one, and you get

```
16 * 15 * 14 * 13 ... * 3 * 2 * 1
```

This is 16 factorial (Written as "16!"). This comes out to a huge number: 2.092279e+13

Now how many bits are required to store a number this big?

```
log2(2.092279e+13) = 44.2501404699
```

Of course, you can't work with 0.25 of a bit, so we have to round up to 45. The most efficient storage of your board takes up 45 bits. However, this is java, so you can't just allocate 45 bits.

Comment: I'm not agree with you: First, I do not store an array of Boards anywhere, and second: the board cannot produce all possible combinations, because of the game-rules. But this is not about the game and its' rules, this is about algorithms which can encode-decode a single matrix of a certain state at a certain moment..

Comment: So you want to see the code to put it into 45 bits?

Comment: I store an object `Board` in a server-RAM. The object contains one property of a primitive data type: `long`. It uses the CPU of the server to encode and decode the data, stored within an object (which, the object, is actually a session attribute). My question is; Do you have a better way to store the state of the board in RAM using less space?

Comment: If you store all the boards in one large byte array, you can pack each board into 48 bits, instead of 64. This is a 25% size reduction.

Comment: But you actually say: "Let's make a factorial of solutions", but to compare a certain state of matrix to all those solutions to get a kind-of "id" of a possible combination, you need to store all combinations in RAM or hardly load the CPU with plenty of calculations for multiple clients, which uses actually more and more RAM for temporary variables you have to create to make those calculations (maybe by using some recursive functions too).

Comment: Or how do you make the comparisons to encode/decode a certain state of board?

Comment: Your solution is a great idea, really. But I just mean it can become a nightmare for cpu's and rams when defining a state.

Comment: You don't need a lookup table to map a combination to a certain board. But you do need a lot of obscure bitwise operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98596/discussion-between-andrew-williamson-and-lowlevel).